# I want to host yii application

Tags: php, mysql, yii, hosting

I have created **yii** app locally. And now I wish to upload the same. I have brought the domain, but am bit confused, as which type of hosting should I go for ?

I have options like **Cpanel(Linux)**, **Parallels Plesk** for Windows, VPS and Dedicated servers  on some sites.

I have developed application using **Yii** 1.1 
and database in MySql.

Could you guys suggest me best hosting available and suitable for me to go with.(Though It should be economic. :-p)
And what things should I consider, or are required while buying a hosting for my **Yii** application.

Edit :
I actually tried hostname/path/to/yii/requirements/index.php and It passed on my friends shared hosting, but I couldn't find proper way to install the Yii on his server space (He has an Windows hosting). 
Someone said I'll require an SSH to run a command ( $php /yii/framework/yiic webapp directory-where-app-will-reside ) to install yii framework on server. 
When called the Tech-support of his hosting agency they said youll have to go with VPS or dedicated server for SSH.

Comment: cPanel, Plesk, etc. suck - they take over the entire system and make it very difficult to configure things to your liking. Get a $5/month VPS from somewhere like Digital Ocean or Amazon EC2's free tier and configure it yourself to your liking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii applications runs on any servers/hosts that support php.

In this case you need a server or host that support **mysql** too.

Its related to your website traffic that choice sharing hosting or VPS.

In your application have to exists a file named `requirement.php` that shows Yii requirements, of course in Yii2. For Yii1:

> 1. [Requirements](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation) ¶ After installing Yii, you may want to verify that your server satisfies Yii's requirements. You can do so by accessing
>      the requirement checker script via the following URL in a Web browser:
>
> http://hostname/path/to/yii/requirements/index.php Yii requires PHP
>   5.1, so the server must have PHP 5.1 or above installed and available to the web server. Yii has been tested with Apache HTTP server on
>   Windows and Linux. It may also run on other Web servers and platforms,
>   provided PHP 5.1 is supported.

However is better your host be on **LAMP** platform.

Comment: I actually tried http://hostname/path/to/yii/requirements/index.php   and  It passed on my friends shared hosting, but I couldn't find proper way to install the Yii on his server space (He has an Windows hosting).  Someone said I'll require an SSH to run a command ( $php /yii/framework/yiic webapp directory-where-app-will-reside ) to install yii framework on server.

When called the Tech-support of his hosting agency they said youll have to go with VPS or dedicated server for SSH.

Comment: You need upload your app code in `public_html` and upload `yii` framework folder to parent `folder of public_html`. Its very simple!!!

Comment: Well, I have uploaded it on my windows server, and now only the layout (i.e. header and footer ) is visible and  for rest there us an error 500
Application runtime path "G:\domain_name\Webapp_name\protected\runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.

Comment: It says: Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process

Comment: Its done, Just had to change permission for the folder. Thank you for the help.